# asp.net Bootstrap not allowing to extend the width of input tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

In my following `View` Bootstrap is not allowing to extend the width of the input tag; moreover, it's aligning the input tag its label and button to the center instead of aligning it to left (as is the case of dropdown above it). I've distributed the Bootstrap's Grid columns to 4+7+1 for label, input, and button. But even if I change this distribution to say, 3+8+1 the input tag's width remains the same. **Question**: How can I make it display so that the label displays on the left most side, button displays on the right most side, and the input tag takes the **entire space** in between it's label and the `Add` button

**View:**

```
<form asp-controller="TestContr" asp-action="TestAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <label asp-for="SelectedYear" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="Model.lstYears"></select><button type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TestDesc" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="TestDesc" class="form-control col-sm-7"/><button type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-info btn-xs col-sm-1">Add</button>
            <span asp-validation-for="TestDesc" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Display page of the above View:**

[image]

If I add inline style `style="width:300px;height:100px;"` to the input tag it still does not increase the width; it only increases the height as shown below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After following a suggestion from user `@MattSpinks` I was able to align the `Add` button to the right and the label to the left; but the input width remains the same as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On your input with `asp-for="TestDesc"`, you've got your `col-sm-7` in the wrong place. That class should be assigned to its parent div. And your button should be at the same DOM level as that parent div as well.

```
<form asp-controller="TestContr" asp-action="TestAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <label asp-for="SelectedYear" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="Model.lstYears"></select><button type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TestDesc" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="TestDesc" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="TestDesc" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-info btn-xs col-sm-1">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In order to align the label to the left, add the `text-align: left` to your control label class:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
  text-align:left;
}
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/9jevfug0/2/

Comment: Your suggestion partially worked in that the `Add` button got aligned to the right; but the rest remains the same. Please see my **UPDATE** section that I just added with an image after applying your suggested settings.

Comment: In order to left align the label, use `text-align:left;` on your control label. See my updated answer. Can you elaborate a little more on the width issue? Exactly what width are you looking for? Based on your code and output, it seems correct. What are you trying to achieve? One thing to note - if you are aligning your button to the right, it might give the illusion that the text box is not filling up the empty space. The empty space is really in your far-right column.

Comment: Your new suggestion about label worked. But the input width and its position remains the same. I need to have input tag taking all the space between  its label and submit button since user needs to have more  space to enter a description of something. So, the submit button still needs to be close (and right side) to the input. But I'm aligning it to the right so the input tag gets more room for me to be able to extend its width. I've replaced the old image with the new one in my UPDATE section so you can see the new change after your new suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately the Bootstrap grid system doesn't work that way. The textbox's width is set according to a percentage (70%) of the parent window. Looking at your images, I can't tell what's going on. It's possible that there is another CSS class that is overriding the width of that text box as well. Can you create a jsFiddle that ilustrates what is happening?

Comment: I don't have any other CSS. It's all default Bootsrap configuration that comes with VS2015 when you create a Web app. But it seems you are right that the width is set to be a fixed percentage or so - since when I added an inline css to set the width to 200px, it decreased the width to 200px but when I changed it to 400px or 500px it did not increase it to more than probably 350px or so. I've created a fiddle at `https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleyahoo/orfeea2t/1/` but not sue if that will be of any help.